# Error while Calling Web Services

Tags: android, web-services, integration

I am a Beginner in both android and Web Services(java soap based).what i was trying to do is request one of the method from the web service.which does not require any parameters for initial testing and catch the response in logcat or a simple text view. Initially it gave me authentication error  provided with a basic http authentication to the web services as it required the same,and then

when i ran the program again it started throwing the exception after this line where i was calling:

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

The Error i get is :

> 04-26 10:10:12.945: I/System.out(322): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT `enter code here`
>   04-26 10:10:12.945: I/System.out(322): ------=_Part_56...@5:13 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40580270)

i Googled a lot and even searched almost all the questions in stack over flow. but didn't find any solution helpful,hence raising this question again. please go through the code and let me know where i am going wrong

```
package com.webservices_demo;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
/*working one*/
public  class FirstAppUI extends Activity {
private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://server name:portNo/ws/TririgaWS";
    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "getApplicationInfo()";
    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://ws.tririga.com/";
    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://servername:port.no/ws/TririgaWS?wsdl";




    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(textView);



        /*Basic Http Authentication to connect*/


Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
 protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("system","admin".toCharArray());
                    }});
                HttpURLConnection c = null;
                try {
                c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(SOAP_ADDRESS).openConnection();
                    System.out.println("=======Connection successful=======");
                //c.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " +
                     //       Base64.encode("system:admin".getBytes(), 0));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();


                }
                c.setUseCaches(false);
                try {
                    c.connect();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }



        SoapObject request=new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
        System.out.println("---------------This is Request sent-------------");
        System.out.println(request.toString());
        System.out.println("---------------End of Request sent--------------");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new      SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

        try

        {
            ///for testing purpose
            System.out.println("======= Path Is=======" +httpTransport.getPath());
            System.out.println("======= Host Is======="+httpTransport.getHost());
            System.out.println("======= Port Is======="+httpTransport.getPort());
            System.out.println("======= String =======" +httpTransport.toString() );
            System.out.println("======= Debugging ======="+ httpTransport.debug);
            //end testing



            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

             System.out.println("result is:- "+ result.toString());
                //FirstAppUI[] getApplicationInfo = RetrieveFromSoap(response);

                TextView actv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                //textView.setHint(getApplicationInfo[0].toString());



            System.out.println("=======Connection Is======="+httpTransport.getConnection() );
            //SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();


            System.out.println("=======Namespace is=======" +response.getNamespace());  
            //Object obj = envelope.bodyIn; 
        textView.setText(response.toString());
            System.out.println("-------------------Body In Response---------------");

            System.out.println(response.toString());

        }

        catch (Exception exception)

        {

            textView.setText(exception.toString());
            String issue= exception.toString();
            System.out.println("====================================================CAUGHT");
            System.out.println(issue);
            exception.printStackTrace();


        }

    }


}
```

This is the Logcat output

```
04-26 10:10:04.454: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.webservices_demo-2.apk' ---
04-26 10:10:05.064: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.064: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.064: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.064: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.064: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.094: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.094: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.094: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.094: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
04-26 10:10:05.544: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;'
04-26 10:10:05.674: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;'
04-26 10:10:05.714: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:05.714: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:05.725: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;'
04-26 10:10:05.725: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:05.734: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:05.734: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:05.734: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:05.734: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:06.104: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:06.104: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:06.104: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:06.104: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:06.104: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:06.104: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:06.114: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
04-26 10:10:06.124: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:06.124: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:06.124: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:06.124: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;': multiple definitions
04-26 10:10:06.124: I/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;'
04-26 10:10:06.164: D/dalvikvm(300): DexOpt: load 167ms, verify+opt 1058ms
04-26 10:10:06.244: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.webservices_demo-2.apk' (success) ---
04-26 10:10:06.244: W/PackageManager(61): Code path for pkg : com.webservices_demo changing from /data/app/com.webservices_demo-1.apk to /data/app/com.webservices_demo-2.apk
04-26 10:10:06.244: W/PackageManager(61): Resource path for pkg : com.webservices_demo changing from /data/app/com.webservices_demo-1.apk to /data/app/com.webservices_demo-2.apk
04-26 10:10:06.244: D/PackageManager(61):   Activities: com.webservices_demo.FirstAppUI com.webservices_demo.EarthQuake com.webservices_demo.Webservices_Demo
04-26 10:10:06.254: I/ActivityManager(61): Force stopping package com.webservices_demo uid=10037
04-26 10:10:06.364: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.webservices_demo-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.webservices_demo-2.apk@classes.dex
04-26 10:10:06.364: D/PackageManager(61): New package installed in /data/app/com.webservices_demo-2.apk
04-26 10:10:06.484: I/ActivityManager(61): Force stopping package com.webservices_demo uid=10037
04-26 10:10:06.534: D/dalvikvm(168): GC_EXPLICIT freed 305K, 52% free 2778K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 52ms
04-26 10:10:06.604: I/ActivityManager(61): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=301 uid=10009 gids={}
04-26 10:10:06.634: W/RecognitionManagerService(61): no available voice recognition services found
04-26 10:10:06.854: I/ActivityThread(301): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
04-26 10:10:07.104: D/dalvikvm(61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 950K, 46% free 4569K/8455K, external 4373K/7373K, paused 108ms
04-26 10:10:07.114: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.webservices_demo-1.apk@classes.dex
04-26 10:10:07.134: D/AndroidRuntime(216): Shutting down VM
04-26 10:10:07.144: D/dalvikvm(216): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 72% free 293K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+1ms
04-26 10:10:07.154: D/jdwp(216): adbd disconnected
04-26 10:10:07.184: I/dalvikvm(216): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
04-26 10:10:07.184: I/AndroidRuntime(216): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-26 10:10:07.774: D/AndroidRuntime(314): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-26 10:10:07.774: D/AndroidRuntime(314): CheckJNI is ON
04-26 10:10:08.344: D/AndroidRuntime(314): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-26 10:10:08.364: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.webservices_demo/.FirstAppUI } from pid 314
04-26 10:10:08.394: I/ActivityManager(61): Start proc com.webservices_demo for activity com.webservices_demo/.FirstAppUI: pid=322 uid=10037 gids={3003}
04-26 10:10:08.404: D/AndroidRuntime(314): Shutting down VM
04-26 10:10:08.414: D/dalvikvm(314): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 69% free 318K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+2ms
04-26 10:10:08.414: D/jdwp(314): adbd disconnected
04-26 10:10:08.494: I/dalvikvm(314): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
04-26 10:10:08.494: I/AndroidRuntime(314): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-26 10:10:09.084: I/System.out(322): executing requestGET http://192.168.1.70:8001/ws/TririgaWS HTTP/1.1
04-26 10:10:11.920: I/System.out(322): ----------------------------------------
04-26 10:10:11.920: I/System.out(322): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
04-26 10:10:11.920: I/System.out(322): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40565650
04-26 10:10:11.925: I/System.out(322): Response content length: 47
04-26 10:10:11.935: I/System.out(322): =======Connection successful=======
04-26 10:10:12.335: I/System.out(322): ---------------This is Request sent-------------
04-26 10:10:12.335: I/System.out(322): getApplicationInfo(){}
04-26 10:10:12.335: I/System.out(322): ---------------End of Request sent--------------
04-26 10:10:12.365: I/System.out(322): ======= Path Is=======/ws/TririgaWS
04-26 10:10:12.365: I/System.out(322): ======= Host Is=======192.168.1.70
04-26 10:10:12.365: I/System.out(322): ======= Port Is=======8001
04-26 10:10:12.365: I/System.out(322): ======= String =======org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE@40571398
04-26 10:10:12.365: I/System.out(322): ======= Debugging =======false
04-26 10:10:12.945: I/System.out(322): ====================================================CAUGHT
04-26 10:10:12.945: I/System.out(322): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT 
04-26 10:10:12.945: I/System.out(322): ------=_Part_56...@5:13 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40580270)* 
04-26 10:10:12.945: W/System.err(322): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT 
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322): ------=_Part_56...@5:13 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40580270) 
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:1413)
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at com.webservices_demo.FirstAppUI.onCreate(FirstAppUI.java:196)
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-26 10:10:12.955: W/System.err(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-26 10:10:12.965: W/System.err(322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check required permissions(Internet) in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the permission is already given.else it would throw the java.net.SocketException: Permission Denied.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
try {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                if (result != null) {

                tvResult.setText(result.getProperty0).toString());

                } else {

                    tvResult.setText("No Output");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
                tvResult.setText(e.toString());
            }
```

hope this will help full.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But it didn't help either

Comment: please check your URLs, SoapAction, NAMESPACE,SOAP_ADDRESS links are properly inserted in constants

Comment: if i try to test the url with the SOAPUI, it gives me the proper output.only thing i am not sure is about the SOAP_ACTION.what it should be exactly